# Methods to autofilling data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a JSON database with information that I would like to autofill in my JavaScript/HTML if a particular element in the array is found. I have an handler event, `onchange` to listen if that particular element is found, it prints all of the info of that particular array. I have it printing into the console, but how would I go about printing this onto my relevant HTML sections?

Are there any documents I should be looking at to help me with this?

The javascript

```
const getAssetInfo = id => {
    $.get( "http://localhost:3000/assets/" + id, function( data ) {
        console.log(data);  
    });
}
$('document').ready(() => {

                    <td><input id='asset_tag_no${count}' type='text' onchange = "getAssetInfo(this.value);" bottom required /></td>
                    <td><input id='manufacturer_serial_no${count}' type='text' bottom required/></td>
                    <td><textarea id='description${count}' type='text' bottom required description></textarea></td>
}
```

The database

```
{
    "assets" : [
        {
            "id": "0946",
            "description" : "SONY - Camera",
            "manufacturer" : "SONY",
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can get some context and provide specific detailed assistance.

Comment: @user1599011 I posted a part of my code, is this relevant enough or should I add more? The console is print the entire asset array, I just want it to print into my JavaScript/HTML

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network's webdocs are great for learning JS and learning how to use and manipulate the DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Comment: awesome this is what i needed thank you